# How to add vertical scrolling to md-tab-group tag in Material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I am really interesting if i could make a horizontal scrollbar for md-tab-group.
I mean not just like an arrow, but add a horizontal scrollbar? Which will be scrolling over  components?

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Item1"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Item2"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Item3"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Item4"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Item5"></md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Here is a simple example and i wonder how could i implement a scrollbar here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please paste here the code you have right now.

Comment: What is `md-tab-group`? Did you mean `md-tabs`? You should just be able to add an `md-content` element inside each `md-tab` but with a fixed height.

Comment: Oh, my bad sorry, i meant horizontal scrollbar. The question is: if there are a lot of items it would be good to have scrollbar there. And is there a way how it could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove arrows using `md-no-pagination` directive. The second step is to override `md-tabs-canvas` style:

```
<md-tabs class="example" md-no-pagination>
  <md-tab ng-repeat="label in array" label="{{label}}">
    Tab {{$index}} content
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

.

```
.example md-tabs-canvas {
  overflow-x: scroll !important
}
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPWeXx